# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2). Server is running

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am getting this strange error on my website as follows: `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)`.
 It occurs when i navigate to a certain page on the site and try to insert data to db

Its strange because it only occurs on that one page in my website. On other pages in my site I am also writing to the same Database, but I get no error and the data is inserted?

Just like to know have any of you experienced this before?

Comment: can it be that you use `localhost` as the hostname on that page and `127.0.0.1` on other pages?

Comment: login to the server and see where the socket is, "show variables like '%sock%'

Comment: Thanks for reply hek2mgl. No thats not it as i have the db connection stored in an include file, and is the same for all files. Also this error only occoured in the last couple of days. It was working..

Comment: Thanks DevZer0. I did it there and I got this result: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock